# Using SnakeMake, how to pass SLURM flags with dashes in their names?

Tags: snakemake

I'm using Snakemake to execute rules on a SLURM cluster.

One of the mandatory flags for this cluster is `ntasks-per-node`, which in a batch script would be specified as e.g. `#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=5`. My understanding is that I need to specify this in a snakemake rule as

```
rule rule_name:
    ...
    resources:
        time='00:00:30', #30 sec
        ntasks-per-node=1
    ...
```

However, running this Snakefile I get

```
SyntaxError in line 14 of .../Snakefile:
keyword can't be an expression
```

because there are dashes in the name. But as far as I can tell, replacing the dashes with underscores doesn't work. What should I do here?

(I'm using the SLURM profile [here](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/slurm) if that matters)

Answer (score 1):

Try quoting. But more importantly, only the resources that are defined in [the `RESOURCE_MAPPING` variable in the `slurm_submit.py`](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/slurm/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.profile_name%7D%7D/slurm-submit.py#L18) will be picked up, and the default cookiecutter does not include an `ntasks-per-node` argument. Hence, quoting alone won't solve the issue.

There are multiple options.

1. **Edit the `slurm_submit.py`**. Add the `ntasks-per-node` argument and provide whatever alias(es) you would like to use.

   ```python
   RESOURCE_MAPPING = {
     "time": ("time", "runtime", "walltime"),
     "mem": ("mem", "mem_mb", "ram", "memory"),
     "mem-per-cpu": ("mem-per-cpu", "mem_per_cpu", "mem_per_thread"),
     "nodes": ("nodes", "nnodes"),
     # some suggested aliases
     "ntasks-per-node": ("ntasks-per-node", "ntasks_per_node", "ntasks")
   }
   ```

   I would only do this if there actually are situations where you might change this value.
2. **Define an invocation-level configuration**. Snakemake's `--cluster_config` parameter can still be used to provide additional configuration settings. In this case, a file like

   ```yaml
   # myslurm.yaml
   __default__:
       ntasks-per-node: 1
   ```

   Then use it with

   ```bash
   snakemake --profile slurm --cluster_config myslurm.yaml
   ```

   This is likely the least work to get going.
3. **Define a global value in the profile**. The cookiecutter profile generator [provides multiple options](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/slurm/blob/a4abc2123e7c7b66f346e8d34601632700ac11a2/README.md#cookiecutter-options) to define global options that don't often need to change for the profile.